# Couchbase 4.5.1: What is beam.smp and why it is consuming too much memory

Tags: couchbase

We are having a single node Couchbase *[4.5.1-2844 Community Edition (build-2844)]*.

For some reason, we are seeing high memory usage on the server. When we log into the server and view the stats we can see that **memcached** and **beam.smp** service is using the memory. 
I need to know, what is the use of **beam.smp** process, and why it is consuming high memory. 
Screenshot for the same is attached to the question. Also I have followed the following links to debug the issues:

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/beam-smp-memory-usage/11843/2

https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-20521

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

beam.smp is the [Erlang vitual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEAM_%28Erlang_virtual_machine%29) used by CouchDB (as CouchBase) for serving and indexing your DB. So it's where the magic happens.